# How to pass value from prarent to square bracket in child component in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Currently I am trying to get value from parent component and then pass it to the child component. So what is the best way to do that, since I am new to Vue. The value from the parent should be accessible inside the square brackets in the child component.

```js
// parent component 
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      formData: data,
      randomNumber: Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1)
    }
  },
  components: {
    VueForm
  },
  methods: {
    numberUpdate(newNumber) {
      console.log(newNumber);
    },
    complete(data) {
      // Send to database here // 
      
      console.log(data.map(d => d.question[randomNumber] + ': ' + d.answer));
      localStorage.setItem('questions', data.map(d => d.question[randomNumber] + ': ' + d.answer));
    }
  }
};
</script>
// child component

<template>
  <div class="vue-form__question">
    <span class="question" :class="{ big: !shouldShowNumber }">{{ question.question[want to pass the data props in here] }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      storedNumber: this.randomNumber(),
    }
  }, 
  props: {
    number: Number,
    question: Object,
    showNumber: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    shouldShowNumber() {
      return this.showNumber && this.number;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: The best way is using `props` in the child element since it's its purpose and you have already used it

Comment: Yes, but how should I apply it to my case, since after reading docs I am still confused how to do that (this is my first time to work with props in vue)

Comment: The data have to be passed here `// Send to database here //`?

Comment: and how do I pass it to 'question.question[want to pass the data props in here]'

Comment: If the child component has to show only one data at a time I suggest to pass to it as `prop` directly the data to be visualized instead of `question: Object`, that means in the parent template you have something like this: `<Child v-bind:question="data.question[index]" />`; and in the child: `<span class="question" :class="{ big: !shouldShowNumber }">{{ question }}</span>`